# Internet connection in MC65

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5, rebex

In MC65, SIM card is already inserted. Any web site can be browsed.

In my application, there is sending email feature using Rebex. Sometimes, it cannot send email. So I tried to browse IE and I'm beware if 3G connection signal appears, sending works properly.

Around connection signal on Screen, there is "H" symbol. What is it?

For my case, it's not good to switch 3G connection by browsing IE. how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Does the Rebex Mail throw any exception when it's unable to send email? Error message might help to diagnose the problem.
- Is it possible to create a SMTP communication log file and include part of it with error message? Following code shows how to do it:

  Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage()
  'todo: set mail message properties

  Dim smtp As New Smtp

  smtp.LogWriter = new Rebex.FileLogWriter("\temp\log.txt", Rebex.LogLevel.Debug)

  smtp.Connect("smtp.example.org")
  smtp.Send(mailMessage)

Edit:

- The 'H' symbol could mean [HSDPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Speed_Downlink_Packet_Access) - high speed data transfer over 3G network.
- Is it possible, that connection is dropped and IExplorer re-establishes connection automatically. In such case you may try to 'dial' connection manually. The [How to establish a GPRS connection for FTP use on .NET CF](http://forum.rebex.net/questions/503/how-to-establish-a-gprs-connection-for-ftp-use-on-net-cf) post shows how.

Comment: I tested your code. Debugging it with cradle, email can send and in log file, it shows "2011-06-19 15:19:43 Opening log file.". But taking out of cradle, when i test sending by using exe, system prompts 'A socket operation encountered a dead network.' and in log file, it shows one new line 'Opening log file'